# I like to eliminate duplicate component from double list and combine it

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I like to combine double lists with duplicate components. It is python code.

import `Tb= [[1],[1,3],[1,2],[5,7]]`

expected output `Tc=[[1,2,3],[5,7]]`

```py
for i in range(len(Tb)):
    print(i)
    for a in Tb[i]:

        for j in range(len(Tb)):
            if a in Tb[j]:
                print('yes')
                Tc.append(list(set(Tb[i]).union(set(Tb[j]))))
                if len(Tb[i]) >= len(Tb[j]):
                    Tb.pop(j)
                elif len(Tb[i])<=len(Tb[j]):
                    Tb.pop(i)

                print(Tb)
                print('#'*20)
                print(Tc)
```

I got list index out of range error.

Comment: I can't understand the intended logic between the input and the desired output. Why is the desired output not, for example, just `[1,2,3,5,7]` instead? Why is it not `[[1], [3], [2], [5, 7]]`?

Comment: I use the number to approach another problem.

Comment: Okay, but I'm not interested in *why* you're trying to do it; I don't understand *what* you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete items from a list while you are iterating through it, the for-loop will eventually try to access items beyond the list size.

It is preferable to use a while loop for in-place deletion so that you can control the progression of the index in accordance with your item manipulations.

```
Tb= [[1],[1,3],[1,2],[5,7]]
i = 1
while i<len(Tb):
    if set(Tb[i]).isdisjoint(Tb[i-1]):
        i += 1
    else:
        Tb[i-1] = sorted({*Tb[i],*Tb.pop(i-1)})
print(Tb)
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 7]]
```

Unless your list is huge, you should consider creating a second list with the merged sublists, and not have worry about index progression at all:

```
Tb  = [[1],[1,3],[1,2],[5,7]]
Tb2 = Tb[:1]
for t in Tb[1:]:
    if set(t).isdisjoint(Tb2[-1]):
        Tb2.append(t)
    else:
        Tb2[-1] = sorted({*t,*Tb2[-1]})
print(Tb2)
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 7]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try to use with huge data sets. It is really helpful that I couldn't figure out for long times.